# Flutter - SingleChildScrollView not scrollable inside SizeTransition

Tags: flutter, dart

As the title suggests, I'm trying to create a container that can expand with SizeTransition. After the container is expanded, the user will enter some texts and it will lead to bottom overflow. So I use SingleChildScrollView. However, the container doesn't seem to be scrollable and overflow still occurs.

Below is part of my code.

```dart
Widget _buildComponentA() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
          //some widgets
          ],
        ),
        SizeTransition(
          child: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                //some widgets
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          sizeFactor: _expand,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

The `_expand` variable is defined as follows.

```dart
_expandController = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      vsync: this,
);
_expandAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_expandController);
```

Thanks!

Comment: try shifting `SingleChildScrollView` widget on top of `SizeTransition` Widget. It should give you the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the above comment, I modified my code and the code below works.

```dart
Widget _buildComponentA() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
          //some widgets
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SizeTransition(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                //some widgets
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          sizeFactor: _expand,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```